# django site name needs to match domain name registered?

Tags: python, django, django-sites

I am new to django framework. I created a site with name "project" and it is working on local machine. Now, I am trying to move on to my test server ("ideometrics.se)". I created a subdomain ("project.ideometrics.se") to access this application from that subdomain. Do I have to change my django site name to "project.ideometrics.se" to make it work on my server ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Django site name does not have anything to do with how it's hosted - it's purely used for internal stuff like displaying the name on the site itself and on emails.